# Does the effect of JMH Blackhole#consume() vary depending on the type of object passed in?

Tags: java, jvm, microbenchmark, jmh

Based on the documentation, I understand that `Blackhole#consume(Object obj)` is used to prevent dead-code elimination when benchmarking Java using JMH.  Is there a difference in behaviour between calling `consume` on an ArrayList object vs iterating through the list and calling `consume` on each individual element?

For example, will there be a difference in behaviour between the two following code samples:

```
  @Benchmark
  @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
  public void someBenchmarkMethod(Blackhole blackhole) {
      List<Integer> ret = //some method that we're benchmarking that returns a list
      blackhole.consume(ret);
  }
```

and

```
  @Benchmark
  @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
  public void someBenchmarkMethod(Blackhole blackhole) {
      List<Integer> ret = //some method that we're benchmarking that returns a list
      for (Integer i : ret) {
          blackhole.consume(i);
      }
  }
```

Is one more accurate (or less variable) than the other?

Comment: The first one is enough to avoid DCE. It is the preferred way. The second sample is meaningless as it pollutes the measurements with the overhead of redundant calls (which will add to the timings of the measured algorithm).

Comment: `blackhole.consume()` should be called just once